# How to remove Grub

Tags: grub2

I recently installed ubuntu and had a dual boot option with Windows 10 enterprise running alongside Ubuntu. I successfully remove Ubuntu but still have the Grub boot launcher.

Every time I start my Surface Pro 3 I have to type exit in Grub. After that, it takes me into my login screen.

The PC is working fine, it is just that the boot launcher comes up every time.

I have seen other tutorials to remove the boot launcher, but I don't have a Windows disk, which all tutorials say I need to have one

Comment: If UEFI see this, also see comment by oldfred on deleting  /EFi/ubuntu folder in ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: That method didn't work.

Comment: Post this above: `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Comment: I'm confused of what you mean @oldfred

Comment: From Ubuntu terminal run `sudo efibootmgr -v` and post above in first post to allow you to keep format, if in comment it becomes unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

Well back in the old days of win98 and the like ,you would open a command prompt and type
 "fdisk /mbr" without the inverted commas and this would get rid of grub, but I dont know whether that command works on recent versions of windows, or whether they still have fdisk even, you can find out from a command prompt by typing fdisk -help  and see what happens

Hope you find this useful